# Accessing a Static Method in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have this class:

```
public static class CsvWriter
    {
       private static StreamWriter _writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\ssis_list.csv");

       public static  StreamWriter Writer 
       {
          get { return _writer; }
       }
    }
```

This is being called from another class

```
 class Program
  {
     ...
     static void GetConnections(string path,string pkgname,string server)
        {

          _writer.WriteLine(myLine);
        }
   }
```

Which has this error

```
The name '_writer' does not exist in the current context
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You may want to be careful about using a static shared Stream class via a static member. Static members are available to all threads in a process - but I/O streams are not implemented to be concurrently accessed from multiple threads.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `CsvWriter.Writer.WriteLine`.